# How to replace part of a filename with input from stdin?

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe, io-redirection, filenames

Let's say I've got a file `ids.txt` with several entries like

```
foo
bar
bam
...
```

for example.
I'd like to use this as input to run a command on some files containing the ids in the filename like `foo_1.gz`, `foo_2.gz`, `bar_1.gz`, `bar_2.gz`, ... and so on.

I tried to refer to the input with `{}`as I saw this working with another command, like so:

```
cat ids.txt | xargs my.command --input1 {}_1.gz --input2 {}_2.gz
```

but it always gives me this error:

```
{}_1.gz no such file or directory
```

Is there any way to treat the input from `cat` as character strings and automatically insert them in the input-file-names for `my.command`?

The problem is also that `my.command` needs two input files each time, so I cannot just use a list with the real file names instead of the `ids.txt`.

Comment: Based on your file names, I suspect you might be interested in our sister site, [bioinformatics.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `-I` option here:

```
$ cat ids.txt | xargs -I{} echo my.command --input1 {}_1.gz --input2 {}_2.gz 
my.command --input1 foo_1.gz --input2 foo_2.gz
my.command --input1 bar_1.gz --input2 bar_2.gz
my.command --input1 bam_1.gz --input2 bam_2.gz
```

Alternatively, use a shell loop:

```
while read id; do 
    my.command --input1 "${id}"_1.gz --input2 "${id}"_2.gz
done < ids.txt
```

That is assuming your IDs have no whitespace or backslashes. If they might, use this instead:

```
while IFS= read -r id; do 
    my.command --input1 "${id}"_1.gz --input2 "${id}"_2.gz
done < ids.txt
```

Finally, you could also use a list with two file names per line:

```
$ cat ids.txt
foo_1.gz foo_2.gz
bar_1.gz bar_2.gz
bam_1.gz bam_2.gz
```

Now:

```
while read file1 file2; do
    my.command --input1 "$file1" --input2 "$file2"
done < ids.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick and detailed answer! It seems to work out with the -I option! :)